# DotNetNuke 6 Manifest | Config component

Tags: dotnetnuke, manifest, config

Looking at how the Config component in the manifest allows us to place new configuration settings in the web.config - it's great! however, I can't seem to get it to add a collection for me and not add in a new block if there's already one there!

In specifics, i'm adding a Web Service reference in the manifest like so:

```
<component type="Config">
      <config>
        <configFile>web.config</configFile>
        <install>
          <configuration>
            <nodes>
              <node path="/configuration" action="update" collision="ignore">
                <system.serviceModel>
                  <bindings>
                    <basicHttpBinding>
                      <binding name="xxx">
                      </binding>
                    </basicHttpBinding>
                  </bindings>
                  <client>
                    <endpoint address="http://xxx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="xxx" contract="xxx" name="xxx" />
                  </client>
                </system.serviceModel>
              </node>
            </nodes>
          </configuration>
        </install>
      </config>
    </component>
```

The  section is added into the web.config even if there's already one of those blocks in the file. What am I doing wrong?

Cheers!

Comment: Is this applicable? If so, my question is solved.

http://blog.usmanahmed.info/beware-of-component-type-config-during-same-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was fixed by adding the uninstall tag. It means this code should work:

```
<component type="Config">
  <config>
    <configFile>web.config</configFile>
    <install>
      <configuration>
        <nodes>
          <node path="/configuration" action="update" collision="overwrite">
            <system.serviceModel>
              <bindings>
                <basicHttpBinding>
                  <binding name="xxx">
                  </binding>
                </basicHttpBinding>
              </bindings>
              <client>
                <endpoint address="http://xxx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="xxx" contract="xxx" name="xxx" />
              </client>
            </system.serviceModel>
          </node>
        </nodes>
      </configuration>
    </install>
    <uninstall>
      <configuration>
         <nodes>
         </nodes>
      </configuration>
    </uninstall>
  </config>
</component>
```

and you need to add each level separately as Bruce Chapman said

Comment: just add the <uninstall> tag after </install>. also it's better to add each node separately as Bruce Chapman said before.

Answer (score 3):

When using the configuration merge, it's best to handle each level of the block separately.

First up, your example only tries to avoid collision on the /configuration element, which is in every web.config file.

Next up, you need to separate out each part - this is important for the uninstall as well.

In your example, you've got several levels - `<system.servicemodel> , <bindings>, <basicHttpBinding>` etc.

What you need to do is split out these independently so they can be identified by the 'key' of each element (ie name, address - whatever it is).  This allows the merge engine to identify a collision and do the update.

The following is just a guess, but should be a useful jumping off point.  It's not easy to figure out and the documentation in this area is a bit sparse.  I ended up deep-diving into the source code to figure this one out myself.

```
<component type="Config">
  <config>
    <configFile>web.config</configFile>
    <install>
      <configuration>
        <nodes>
          <node path="/configuration" targetpath="/configuration/system.serviceModel" action="update" collision="ignore">
            <system.serviceModel>
              <bindings>
                 <basicHttpBinding>
                 </basicHttpBinding>
              </bindings>
              <client>
              </client>
            </system.serviceModel>
          </node>
          <node path="/configuration/system.serviceModel/bindings/basicHttpBinding" action="update" key="name" collision="overwrite">
              <binding name="xxx">
              </binding>
          </node>
          <node path="/configuration/system.serviceModel/client" action="update" key="address" collision="overwrite">
             <endpoint address="http://xxx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="xxx" contract="xxx" name="xxx" />
          </node>
        </nodes>
      </configuration>
    </install>
  </config>
</component>
```

**Edit:**
The targetpath-attribute has to be written in lower case, otherwise the installer will create duplicate elements. (Original answer: targetPath)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing collision to overwrite instead of Ignore

ex:

```
 <component type="Config">
     <config>
       <configFile>web.config</configFile>
       <install>
         <configuration>
           <nodes>
             <node path="/configuration/dotnetnuke/sitemap/providers" action="update" key="name" collision="overwrite">
               <add name="DNNSimpleArticleSiteMapProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Modules.dnnsimplearticle.Providers.Sitemap.Sitemap, DNNSimpleArticle" providerPath="~\DesktopModules\dnnsimplearticle\Providers\Sitemap\" />
             </node>
           </nodes>
         </configuration>
       </install>
       <uninstall>
         <configuration>
           <nodes />
         </configuration>
       </uninstall>
     </config>
   </component>
```

Comment: Tried that Chris, still creates a new section.

Will it be because i'm adding an entire collection with no "key"?

Comment: Not sure, your comment above might be correct, I didn't see that before replying

Comment: The problem with overwriting in this case is that there could be other services under the system.serviceModel node, from other modules.